# How to resolve Information - Not a valid month error?

Tags: informatica-powercenter

When running a PowerCenter session that uses an Oracle database view as a source the session fails with one of the following errors:

ORA-01843: Not a valid month.

In SqL developer it runs without any issues

Column : Report_date : Data Type : date.

In mapping parameter variable defined as String

Passing report date dynamically using  param file &Control table

Select * from ABC
Where report_date=to_char(31-MAR-21,'DD-MON-RR')

--Error: not valid month

Could you please advise on it

Answer (score 3):

You need to put single quotes around infa mapping parameter. Like this -

First calculate Report_Date and put the value in infa param file in correct format. You can use control table too. But you need to create a param file from that.
param file should look like

```
[folder.workflow.session]
$$Report_Date='21-Oct-2021'
```

Then in mapping you can call it in source qualifier as -

```
Select * from ABC Where report_date=to_char('$$Report_Date','DD-MON-RR')
```

single quote will ensure your data is passed as string.

Now, if youdont want to use param file, you can use control file as a new source and join with the SQL above to get desired result. But first approach is faster.